# My code works for text files but not jpegs

Tags: curl, libcurl, s3fs

I've got a fork of s3fs-fuse I'm working on. My job is to encrypt the files transparently with RC4. I've added the encryption to the FdEntity::Read and Write functions (found in fdcache.cpp) but when I try to copy a jpeg file (17kb) it fails (the file is copied, but the image is corrupt) and according to cmp, the files differ beginning after 4096 bytes. However, a 198kb text file is copied without error.

Here's what I know: 4kb is the size of a block.
However, s3fs doesn't go into "multipart mode" until 20mb. Even then, I've disabled multipart with `-o nomultipart` (I'm also using `-o direct_io`).
So it's probably not because of multipart uploading.

Any idea what might be triggering after 4kb but only on jpeg files? Could it be related to binary-vs-text files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. When you use RC4 to decrypt data in parts, the size of each of the parts must be the same as it was when they were encoded. However, the sizes that Read received as arguments were larger than the sizes that Write received (Read would be asked to read 20480 bytes, while Write capped out at 4096). So if I tried to read that entire 20480 byte section of data, the encryption would fail. My solution was to clamp the amount read to 4096, even if I was asked to read more. S3fs automatically called the function additional times to compensate. This solution may not be technically airtight: There's no guarantee that every non-final section of data was encrypted in 4096b blocks by Write, and there's no guarantee that the final section was always encrypted at that alignment in a particular size (total size modulo 4096). However, this solution was sufficient for my purposes.

The problem only appeared on the jpeg and not the text file because the text file was the same string repeated over and over and over again.